VSCode not closing single/double quotes following equals sign for shell scripts(bash)
Operating System
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (but I had this problem on Ubuntu 22)

VSCode Version
Version: 1.92.2
Commit: fee1edb8d6d72a0ddff41e5f71a671c23ed924b9
Date: 2024-08-14T17:29:30.058Z
Electron: 30.1.2
ElectronBuildId: 9870757
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.10.7-061007-generic

Autoclosing quotes directly following equals sign or after an echo isn't working. i.e.
typing variable=" results in variable=" instead of variable="". However, typing variable= " (which I know is bad syntax for bash!) will result in variable= "". It's the same thing for single quotes. The echo command has a similar but opposite issue. Typing echo " results in echo " instead of echo "" and typing echo" results in echo"".
I've check my keyboard layout following another post that said to make sure it's set to US only and not US international and I'm good there.
I've check and tried changing the language specific settings for shell script, setting the following:
"[shellscript]": {
      "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
      "editor.autoClosingDelete": "always",
      "editor.autoClosingOvertype": "always",
      "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "always",
      "editor.autoSurround": "quotes",
    }

That didn't work. I also tried setting those settings on a global basis:
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
"editor.autoClosingDelete": "always",
"editor.autoClosingOvertype": "always",
"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "always",

That didn't work.
I also saw a post about html attributes auto making quotes, typing name= results in name="" and so I disabled that thinking maybe an issue there because the equals sign and no change.
Any help/suggestions appreciated as I've lost my patience with quotes and bash.

The VSCode issue tracker is this way  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues
